# vbnet textbox fields to excel cells

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am using the following code to create a new instance of an excel template.
I fill the cells from fields in the vbnet application, pass them to excell cells. I there a way to do it to an excel bookmark, field, reference name as i did not find anything

```
        xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlApp.Visible = True
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("invoice.xlsx")
        xlWorksheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("invoice")

        xlWorksheet.Cells(4, 2) = Nameofemployee
        xlWorksheet.Cells(5, 2) = Title
        xlWorksheet.Cells(6, 2) = Job
        xlWorksheet.Cells(4, 8) = site
        xlWorksheet.Cells(5, 8) = today()
```

what happened the template changed and shifted the cell position.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, needed to define a name in the cell then paste as Range

```
        xlWorksheet.Range("nameofcell").Value = nameofemployee
        xlWorksheet.Range("nameofcell").Value = Title
        xlWorksheet.Range("nameofcell").Value = job
        xlWorksheet.Range("nameofcell").Value = site
        xlWorksheet.Range("nameofcell").Value = today()
```